# Script to edit program launch command in terminal

Tags: dual-boot, mount, rhythmbox

I have a dual boot Ubuntu 14.04/Win7 pc.

I have all my music in my Windows drive (D: drive). If I need to play from library in rhythmbox, I have to first open/mount my D: drive, so that rhythmbox can recognise the source. Otherwise, the library can't play the song.

I want to edit the rhythmbox's launch command so that it can open D: drive before it opens rhythmbox. How can I do that?

Comment: can be done, but then the right-click "open with" would not work any more with rhythmbox. is there a reason not to automount the partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies.

I wanted to **auto-mount my D: drive at startup.**

What I did, was found the UUID of my drive by checking its properties.
Next, I added this command to **gnome-session-properties (press Alt+F2 and search)** -

```
udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/disk/by-uuid/<place_disk_UUID_here>
```

Where I placed my disk's UUID at the end as asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `autofs` for doing some sort of it. `autofs` will only mount a certain path if you access it.

Therefore you could configure Rhythmbox do scan your library on that path. It is not exactly what you said but it fits.

Other even simpler option could be mount your Windows partition on boot time (I would go with it because it is the easiest way but I have assumed that you don't want to do it).

Check [autofs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs) at community wiki.